# Does pole emploi register your name if you only have récépissé

Tags: france, unemployment-benefits

Does pole emploi register your name if you only have récépissé?

Comment: Hello. It is difficult to understand what exactly is your question and it's context. Pole Emploi does not _register names_ and there are many different _récépissé_ in France.

Comment: I came into France 1 year ago and right now they have given me récépissé till June 2020. Préfecture said they would call me when my carte is ready. So I just want to know will pôle emploi register my name with that récépissé.

Comment: When you say “register your name” are you asking if pôle emploi will accept your request to be part of the list of unemployed persons (and thus have the official status of being unemployed)? This depends on what type of titre de séjour (and récépissé) you currently have.

Comment: Yes . I need attestation of pôle emploi. Currently I have récépissé and there it is written that I am not authorized to work. So will they listed me or Not ?

Comment: I doubt that _Pole Emploi_ will register you if your _récépissé de demande de titre de séjour_ explicitly prohibits working. But I couldn't find an authoritative source.

Comment: What about when you got have the carte séjour but in remarque it’s written visiter. Will pôle emploi inscrit my name ??